# Confusing C++ Output

Tags: c++, output

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 main() {
   if (sizeof(int) > -1)
       printf("True");
   else
       printf("False");
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this code gives answer as **False** while the **size of integer is 4.**

Comment: sizeof returns an unsigned value, so compiler will interpret right hand side as unsigned too and will make it a very large positive number. See live demo here : https://godbolt.org/z/vo6qhd588 (note the value : 4294967295, that's your "-1")

Comment: @PepijnKramer That really should be added as an answer.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: That's an answer, not a comment. You should post it as such.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I agree with the others, you should post an answer.  But to be a *good* answer you should explain why the -1 is being cast to unsigned rather than sizeof being cast to int.

Comment: Note that for C++, you should be using `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>`. Formally speaking, the latter doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: Please tag this C, it has nothing to do with C++.